# In prestashop 1.6, Browser caching issue

Tags: caching, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop 1.6, there is a caching issue (i think). when i disable or update content on website, it's not showing. Everytime, i have to press ctrl+shift+R to show the new changes. I disabled the caching from backend. But, the issue still exist.

Comment: Do you have a cache module like APC or Xcache? Varnish? Local installation or on a web server?

Comment: @Matteo Enna This is happening on a Web server not a local installation. Caching, i disabled them all in the prestashop module.